# Why is multipart form data file upload got different content types on different systems?

Tags: file-upload, multipartform-data, mime-types, content-type

I am hosting a page which has the following HTML form:

```html
<form action="#" id="upload_form">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="update" onchange="document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Update" disabled>
</form>
```

It uploads the form data like this:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var d = new FormData(document.getElementById("upload_form"));
    var x = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    x.open("POST", "/update", true);

    x.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e)
    {
        if (e.lengthComputable)
        {
            document.getElementById("prg").value = e.loaded / e.total;
        }
    }, false);

    x.send(d);
});
```

I then upload a tgz file created with the following options: `tar -czvf ...`.

If I open the webpage on a Mac (Safari) and do the upload the request body looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryjZ4I2JC5nV3APLVy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="update"; filename="test.tgz"
Content-Type: application/x-gzip

<data>

------WebKitFormBoundaryjZ4I2JC5nV3APLVy--

=======================================
```

If I open the webpage on Windows (Chrome) and do the upload the request body looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryjZ4I2JC5nV3APLVy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="update"; filename="test.tgz"
Content-Type: application/x-compressed

<data>

------WebKitFormBoundaryjZ4I2JC5nV3APLVy--

=======================================
```

You can see that the content type is different. When the server gets the data out of the response and stores it in a file, it works properly when it came from a Mac but not when it came from Windows.

Came from Mac:

```
$ file test.tgz 
test.tgz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Mon Jul  3 20:42:29 2023, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 2560
```

Came from Windows:

```
$ file test.tgz 
test.tgz: data
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Edit:
If I make the file a tar.gz rather than a .tgz both Windows and Mac send the x-gzip content type.